# URL images are smaller than the original image

Tags: android, image, xamarin

I am using xamarin studio. I have to download a bunch of  images  from a web service. I only get their url and then I use the following code to make the images bitmap

```
     SetContentView (Resource.Layout.test);
        ImageView img = FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.image);
        Bitmap bitimage = GetImageBitmapFromUrl ("http://apk.payment24.co.za/promotions/engensa/muffin.png");
        img.SetImageBitmap (bitimage);


   public  static Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
    {

        Bitmap imageBitmap = null;
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {


            var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
            if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            }
        }

        return imageBitmap;
    }
```

The problem is the image I display is very small. If I manually download the images from the url and add it to the project it works perfectly fine. 
My image view settings are with: match_parent and height: wrap_content.
How can I get the original size of the images if I download it via url.
Please see this link to see how the image look http://postimg.org/image/c3kbsz903/

Comment: first of all I would check the bounds of that image in the debugger to check them without any UI logic. I think that your UI control will scale the image implicitly.

Comment: Hi please see the edit I made. And the problem is if I download this image form the url and save it to the project with with: match_parent and height: wrap_content. the picture is displayed properly. but if I use this method the image returned is very  small

Comment: any other suggestions none  them worked

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `android:adjustViewBounds ="true"` and `android:src="@drawable/` attribute in your Imageview

```
    <ImageView
   layout_width="match_parent"
   layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:adjustViewBounds ="true"
   android:src="@drawable/ dummy drawable/>
```

Please Check [ScaleType](http://etcodehome.blogspot.in/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html) in android .

Comment: Why must I add android:src="@drawable/ / ? I get a error saying no resources found that matchers the given etc... so sadly did not work

Comment: You can add ic_drawable there

Comment: Add android: scaleType fitXY

Comment: the problem is as follows. If I download the image manual from the url and place it in the xml (it looks fine) but if I use the code to download it and place it in the image container the image is much smaller than the original and that is the current problem I am having

Answer (score 0):

You stated that your view attributes are something like this

```
<ImageView
   layout_width="match_parent"
   layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In order to have the original size of the image, you must set the `layout_width` attribute of your ImageView to `wrap_content` so that the ImageView won't use its parent's width but will adapt to the image original size.

Comment: makes no difference in the size